# How can a .net-core application read the keyboard state, irrespective of the operating system?

Tags: c#, .net-core, io

I am trying to detect the pressed keys in an application for Linux and Windows. Text can be read using `System.Console`, but that fails when multiple keys are pressed simultaneously. On Windows, using regular .net, the keyboard state can be read using `System.Windows.Input`. But how can I do the same on Linux? Or is there another better solution for all of .net-core?

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input` contains exactly this functionality. It can be added to the project through the NuGet package `MonoGame`.

Comment: Ok, this does not seem to do anything at all. The keyboard doesn't register any pressed keys. Though it should work according to its documentation?